# confusion on the use of parameter in forEach() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, new-operator

I am new to learning `JavaScript`, while i was going through `mdn` articles, I find that you can use `forEach()` method instead of for loop to put `eventhandlers` in each of the button element.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(function(x) {  

  x.onclick = function() {
    alert("hello world")
  };

});
```

I am just confused on what is x representing, and if it is representing all of the buttons and how does it work, I just don't understand. Can anyone help me to get clear understanding of the use of x here as a parameter?

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is the docs on the NodeList's forEach

Answer (score 0):

You may find this to have a neat breakdown of the .forEach method: [.forEach Primer](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-foreach-how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-js/)

Basically, the `x` is a parameter that would represent each item in the array that you are going to store in `buttons`.